Symplectic transformation for which componentwise area is not conserved in phase space
Consider two elements the phase space $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Denote the coordinates $x=(x_q,x_p)=(x_q^1,\ldots, x_q^n,x_p^1,\ldots, x_p^n)$ and the same for $y$. If we consider the bilinear form $$\omega(x,y):=\left| \begin{matrix} x_q^1 & y_q^1 \\ x_p^1 & y_p^1 \end{matrix} \right|+\ldots+\left| \begin{matrix} x_q^n & y_q^n \\ x_p^n & y_p^n \end{matrix} \right|,$$ the linear map $A:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is said to be symplectic if $\omega(Ax,Ay)=\omega(x,y)$. In other words, the sum of the state-space-componentwise areas are unchainged by the application of the linear map. I was wondering what would be an example where the value of the $2\times 2$ determinants change under the linear map, i.e.
$$\left| \begin{matrix} (Ax)_q^i & (Ay)_q^i \\ (Ax)_p^i & (Ay)_p^i \end{matrix} \right|\neq\left| \begin{matrix} x_q^i & y_q^i \\ x_p^i & y_p^i \end{matrix} \right|\text{ for some } i=1\ldots n$$
but the sum of the determinants is conserved and if such an example occurs for practical systems where the linear map is the jacobian of the hamiltonian flow of the system. Also I am curious on what it means on an intuitive level that the componentwise area is not conserved.
